# Set data item value to tag property in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How can I set one of my data item from my datasource to a control property in datagrid in WPF?

*

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdFilter" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource RowHeader}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn >
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Button x:Name="btnCalendar" Click="btnCalendar_Click">X</Button>
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

*

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show some demo codes to light your question?

Comment: There is a field called IsDate so I pretend to use this field to hide/show the btnCalendar using visualization property. Something like :
<Button x:Name="btnCalendar" Visualization="{Binding IsDate}" Click="btnCalendar_Click">X</Button>

In addition I want to save key information in Tag field of the button too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button x:Name="btnCalendar" Click="btnCalendar_Click" Tag="{Binding Name}">X</Button>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDate}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="btnCalendar" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Great Thanks!!! I'm newbie in WPF. What about the tag property ? I want to save data in button tag property too. I tried the following without success.


<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDate}" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="btnCalendar" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="btnCalendar" Property="Tag" Value="0" />
</DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>

Comment: What's the type of  `value`? bool? Just want the `Tag=0` while `Value=False` and default to be `Tag=null`?

Comment: No, in this case I want to store a string there in order to get it once the user clicks on the button. There is another value called "Name"

Comment: So, you want the `Tag` = `Name`?

Comment: Try adding `Tag="{Binding Name}"` on the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177584/discussion-between-iron-and-carlos-a-b).

Comment: It works,,! Many thanks again you save me a lot of time.

Comment: Is there a way to bind this property to a local function (true/false) sending a parameter in my codebehind?? Thanks!